# stored procedure returns wrong value

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, procedure

I have a stored procedure that keeps giving me wrong answer. I asked the procedure to return the value of motor insurance. I run the procedure and give me the total of motor insurance premium but if I run it for the 4th time it give me the ageRange select statement value.
I moved the code into a new procedure but still the same.

My code

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `cal_motor_qoute`(in 
coverID int , in dob date,
in sumMotor double , out QMsg varchar(200))
BEGIN
declare policy_cover , total , insRatio, ageExtra double;
declare ageRange int;
declare price_list  varchar(200);

SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),dob) / 365.25 AS ageRange from dual;


if (coverID = 1) then
set policy_cover = 0.002;
elseif (coverID = 2) then
set policy_cover = 0.0025;
elseif (coverID = 3) then
set policy_cover = 0.003;
elseif (coverID = 4) then
set policy_cover = 0.0035;
end if;

if ( ageRange < 25) then
set ageExtra = 0.0005;
else
set ageExtra = 0.000;
end if;

set insRatio = policy_cover + ageExtra;
set total = (sumMotor * insRatio )* 10;

set QMsg = concat('total Premium is: ',total);
select @QMsg;
END
```

Any help please..

Comment: Question: why is this done in a stored procedure and not in the application code?

Comment: @Galz its a php application, stored procedure could complete the job

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),dob) / 365.25 AS ageRange from dual;
```

will not set the variable `ageRange`, but it will do a `select` (of the calculated value) and name the column of the resultset `ageRange`.

The (or rather: one) way to set the value of your variable is to use `into`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),dob) / 365.25 into ageRange from dual;
```

Although this is probably not the most precise way to calculate the age of a person anyway. You might want to replace

```
if ( ageRange < 25) then
```

with

```
if ( dob > date_sub(now(), interval 25 year) ) then
```

Comment: it works !! thanks but another small question. I need to run the code twise to have the new value because in somehow the resault is not updated from the first time.

Comment: @imohd23 Not sure what you mean. Could you add an example for that, so how you call the procedure, and what (doesn't) happen. Btw, using a function instead of a procedure looks like a more logical choice for this - but then again, it depends on how you use/call it.